# What determines military victory?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion

I was playing a game of Sins of a Solar Empire: Rebellion and all of a sudden it was declared that I won via a military victory.  However I haven't finished conquering the other guy's planets yet and I was given the option to keep playing.

What are the exact conditions when the game is declaring a militaristic victory?  Since it doesn't seem to be "destroy all of the other guy's planets/fleets" anymore.

At the victory conditions screen it doesn't say anything about a military victory (while the other guy has units left).

Comment: Did the AI enemy surrender?

Comment: @YiJiang I didn't see any messages regarding that, and since I wasn't attacking him at the time (was dealing with pirates) I don't see why he would.

Comment: @YiJiang after poking around, I'm forced to conclude that somehow both AIs surrendered at the same time and I didn't see the message, there's no other way to obtain military victory without destroying the other races.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A.I. can surrender. To win a military victory you can either kill all players and thier planets/fleets, or the A.I. can surrender. It more likely they will surrender, so don't worry too much, athough frustrating to win premuturely just because the A.I. doesn't want to continue. Things that can increase the chance of them surrendering is a much bigger fleet than them while they have a smaller one via lack of resources to fill their extra fleet supplie or you cutting them down. It's most likely to happen when they only have a handful of planets left and a considerably small fleet when compared to yours. It also explains why the A.I. die mid game even though they still have some planets whether there is anyone attacking them or not.